# More efficient way to create a list in Ruby

Tags: ruby, for-loop

Just working with the 2-9 in a deck of cards.

What is the preferred and/or most efficient way to get the deck created in Ruby?

Is it what I have below, or how else can/should I do it?

```
deck = []
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"]

for x in suits
  for y in 2..9
    w = y.to_s
    deck.push(w+" of "+x)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"]
deck = suits.product((2..9).to_a).map { |x,y| "#{y} of #{x}" }
```

If you want all 52 cards:

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"]
faces = { 1 => 'Ace', 11 => 'Jack', 12 => 'Queen', 13 => 'King' }
deck = suits.product((1..13).to_a).map { |x,y| "#{faces[y]||y} of #{x}" }
# => Ace of spades, 2 of spades, ..., King of spades, Ace of diamonds, etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

I like `product` w/ a block

```
a, suits = [], ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"]
suits.product((2..9).to_a) {|t,n| a << "#{n} of #{t}"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just use maps:

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"]
deck = suits.map { |d| (2..9).map { |x| "#{x} of #{d}" } }.flatten
```

But the efficiency is mostly the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
suits.flat_map {|s| (2..9).map{|r| "#{r} of #{s}"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
suits, values, deck = %w(spades hearts diamonds clubs), [*2..9], values.product(suits).map { |card| card * ' of ' }
```